# c++ OpenCV memory management

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, free

I'm trying to build a program that recognises objects through template matching.
Whenever I select my ROI the program memory starts to gain 2-3 mbs per second and after 20-30 minutes the program crashes because it uses to much memory.

I think the problem starts somewhere in the code below but I have no idea where, and how to somehow free the memory without corrupting the program.

Could someone give me a lead on how to fix this problem?

```
void testApp::update()
{

vidGrabber.grabFrame();    
    if (vidGrabber.isFrameNew())    
    {
        colorImg.setFromPixels(vidGrabber.getPixels(), camWidth,camHeight);
        if(subjectIsDefined)
            {           
                IplImage *result = cvCreateImage(cvSize(camWidth - subjectImg.width + 1, camHeight - subjectImg.height + 1), 32, 1);
                cvMatchTemplate(colorImg.getCvImage(), subjectImg.getCvImage(), result, CV_TM_SQDIFF);
                double minVal, maxVal;
                CvPoint minLoc, maxLoc;
                cvMinMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, 0);
                subjectLocation.x = minLoc.x;
                subjectLocation.y = minLoc.y;
            }
    }
}



void testApp::mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button)
{
//End tracking and normalize subject frame
if(subjectFrame.width < 0)
{
    subjectFrame.x += subjectFrame.width;
    subjectFrame.width *= -1;
}

if(subjectFrame.height < 0)
{
    subjectFrame.y += subjectFrame.height;
    subjectFrame.height *= -1;
}
isSelectingTrackingRegion = false;
subjectLocation.x = subjectFrame.x;
subjectLocation.y = subjectFrame.y;


//Copy selected portion of the image to the subject image;
subjectImg.allocate(subjectFrame.width, subjectFrame.height);   
colorImg.setROI(subjectFrame);
subjectImg = colorImg;
colorImg.resetROI();
subjectIsDefined = true;
}
```

Comment: Use valgrind or a similar tool to provide more evidence for the memory leak cause.

Comment: c api cvCreateImage needs a cvReleaseImage to give memory free. better use c++ api cv::Mat which uses reference counting to release memory automatically

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `cvReleaseImage()` for all the image `Iplmage` which you have created in your program. You have to be careful to find the correct place to write `cvReleaseImage(image name)` because once you release the memory related to an image, you can not access that image again.

**Suggestion:** Don't use `IplImage`. That's the old c api of OpenCV. Now a days, you can use `Mat` images which can manage the memory themself. The advantage of using `Mat` is that you don't need to think about freeing the memory.